# Prove in any set of 51 positive integers,there are 11 integers $d_1<d_2<…<d_{11}$ with the property that $5^{d_1}+5^{d_2}+…+5^{d_{11}}$ is multiple 11

Tags: number-theory

Show that in any set of 51 positive integers, there are 11 integers
$d_{1} < d_{2}\ <  ---  < d_{11}$ with the property that the sum
$5^{d_1} + 5^{d_2} +    + 5^{d_{11}}$is an integer-multiple of 11:

Using FERMAT's Little Theorem, each one of the terms will be congruent to 1 Mod(2) and their sum will be equal to 11 and thus divisible by 11.  But I just need a good logical step of using modular arithmetic to derive the above fact.  Could someone help me!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $5$ has order $5$ modulo $11$, for $5^5\equiv 1\pmod{11}$.

Thus, modulo $11$, the $5^{d_i}$ can take on at most $5$ distinct values.

Now use the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: Here is where the set of 51 integers come into play where you use pigeonhole principle of (5 distinct values *10 + 1).

Comment: Yes, there are at least $11$ numbers in the list that have the same remainder. Pick any $11$ of them. Their sum is divisible by $11$.

Comment: When you say remainder, you mean 1 I guess?

Comment: No, I do not necessarily mean $1$. There are $5$ possible remainders, namely $5,3,4,9,1$. I am saying that among the $51$ $5^{d_i}$, at least one of these occurs $11$ or more times. For if they all occurred $\le 10$ times, that would only account for at most $50$. Perhaps the remainder $9$ occurs $48$ times, the remainder $1$ occurs once, and the remainder $3$ occurs twice.

Comment: Now I got it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome.  The Pigeonhole Principle, though the idea is simple, can be tricky to apply.